# iOS Error Trying to Attach 2 SQLite databases

Tags: ios, database, xcode, sqlite

I'm a Ios developer and i'm having a problem with attaching 2 SQLite db's .
We are getting this error when running:

```
Error calling sqlite3_step (1: SQL logic error or missing database) SQLITE_ERROR
2012-06-19 11:10:19.658 °°°°°°°[453:707] DB Query: ATTACH DATABASE '/var/mobile/Applications/A05034A8-F5AF-45AA-B520-DF2BBEBB800B/Documents/Meals.db' AS mealDB
2012-06-19 11:10:19.672 °°°°°°°[453:707] Err 1: no such table: Meal
2012-06-19 11:10:19.680 °°°°°°°[453:707] Error calling sqlite3_step (1: SQL logic error or missing database) SQLITE_ERROR
2012-06-19 11:10:19.684 °°°°°°°[453:707] DB Query: ATTACH DATABASE '/var/mobile/Applications/A05034A8-F5AF-45AA-B520-DF2BBEBB800B/Documents/Meals.db' AS mealDB
2012-06-19 11:10:19.693 °°°°°°°[453:707] Err 1: no such table: MealItem
2012-06-19 11:10:19.698 °°°°°°°[453:707] ERREUR
```

After attaching, we are trying to collect data . He is not finding the table we are searching in: Err 1: no such table: MealItem or Err 1: no such table: Meal.

It gets even stranger!
When we test the same code in Sim with iOS 5.0 it works !
Data is returning from the request!
Still getting this error a few times though :

```
Error calling sqlite3_step (1: SQL logic error or missing database) SQLITE_ERROR
2012-06-19 11:10:19.684 °°°°°°°[453:707] DB Query: ATTACH DATABASE '/var/mobile/Applications/A05034A8-F5AF-45AA-B520-DF2BBEBB800B/Documents/Meals.db' AS mealDB
```

We tried attaching the 2 databases in sqlight manager, and this was successful.
This result database also worked in the application .
It seems like iOS has a problem attaching databases .
Or we made an error somewhere .

We are searching for a solution without any luck so far.

Here some code :
(Using FMDatabase api)

```
- (FMDatabase *) attachMealDatabase:(FMDatabase *) db {


    if (![db open]) {
        NSLog(@"Could not open db.");
        return nil;
    }else {

    }

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    //const char * mainDBPath = [[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Main.db"] UTF8String];
    const char * mealDBPath = [[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Meals.db"] UTF8String];



    NSString *attachSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"ATTACH DATABASE \'%s\' AS mealDB", mealDBPath];


    [db beginTransaction];

    [db executeUpdate:attachSQL];
    [db commit];
    //[db close];

    return db;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try attaching the database in the `FMDatabase` layer instead of the viewcontrollers.
We did it in the Db open function by calling the following function:

```
-(void)attachDb{

  NSArray paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  const char  secondDBPath = [[documentDirectory    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Second.db"] UTF8String];

  if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)
  {
    NSString *strSQLAttach = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ATTACH DATABASE \'%s\' AS SECOND", secondDBPath ];
    char *errorMessage;

    if (sqlite3_exec(db, [strSQLAttach UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errorMessage) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        DLog(@"Great Success!");
    }
  }    
}
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: Yes it worked :)   Still have no idea why the other code was failing though :p